# Jquery jcrop plugin image issue

Tags: php, jquery, jcrop

I use jquery plugin (jcrop) for image crop in my project. After cropping, i use .ajax method to upload cropped and original image. I use following steps to done this (as shown in image)

Step 1 : This is initial stage before upload.
Step 2 : I select an image, crop, and upload using ajax. This function work ok.
Step 3 : Now i remove this image, clear my database as well as remove images(delete from server).
Step 4 : I select new image from computer, crop and upload to server and response is shown to lower image area.

Now problem is, it working fine on localhost, but on server it shows old cropped image. When i refresh this page, it show new image. I look at my server folder, when i remove image it also deleted. then how it show me old image.

Can anyone please show me whats going on?

[image]

Comment: The old image is probably loaded from cache, see what happens if you manually empty all caches before step 4

Comment: You could pass a unique value to with the image name, this would force PHP to re-check the image.

Comment: i am calling old image by id after cropping and saving. But old image shown. After refresh its ok. Its cache problem, but what is solution? It works good in mozilla but problem comes in google crome.

Comment: Aha, thanks @ICanHasCheezburger. This unique ID trick wirks for me.